# while loop slice

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I am trying to use a while loop to slice up a big hunk of text such that each piece is under 995 characters long and ends with a period. I've almost gotten it to work, except the very last chunk never gets pushed into the array. Why is that?

```
function divideByPunctuation() {
    var chunkArray = [];
    var textHunk = prompt();
    var textLength = textHunk.length;
    var currentLoc = 0;
    var i = 995;
    while (currentLoc <= textLength) {
        if (textHunk[i] === ".") {
            if (i > textLength) {
                chunkArray.push(textHunk.slice(currentLoc, textLength));
                break;
            } else {
                chunkArray.push(textHunk.slice(currentLoc, i));
                currentLoc += i;
                i = currentLoc + 995;
            }

        } else {
            i--
        }
    }
    console.log(chunkArray[0]);
    console.log(chunkArray[1]);
    console.log(chunkArray[2]);
    console.log(chunkArray[3]);
};
divideByPunctuation();​
```

Comment: The while-loops condition should be `currentLoc < textLength`. Also, you might use `.charAt(i)` instead of bracket notation which is not supported by ancient IE.

Comment: What do you want it do do in the case that there is a string longer than 995 characters with no period?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a nice built-in function for this sort of thing.

```
a = "Hi there. Here's a test sentence. Here's another one";
a.split(". ");
["Hi there", "Here's a test sentence", "Here's another one"]
```

Comment: I need this split into chunks as close to 995 characters as possible, so .split() won't help me

Comment: Which constraint wins? What if there is a sentence longer than 995 characters?

Comment: has to be under 995 characters, regardless if the sentence is longer. Not that there are many 1000 character sentences